# Can I activate Angus Mackenzie between two combat phases?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's imagine I'm in a multiplayer game and I'm happy with an opponent's first attack, so I don't activate [Angus Mackenzie](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAngus%20Mackenzie%5d). The active player resolves combat, then casts [Fury of the Horde](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFury%20of%20the%20Horde%5d) and swings at me.

Is it too late to activate Angus, because it's after a combat damage step? Can it be activated because we can see there'll be another combat damage step later this turn?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is too late.
This is covered by [the rules under 506.6](http://mtg.gamepedia.com/Combat_phase), in particular 506.6d and 506.6g.

Spells which may be cast only before a particular point in the combat phase, but not only during combat, may only be cast before the stated point of the first combat phase. And activated abilities share the same restrictions.

> 506.6g Rules 506.6 and 506.6a–f apply to abilities that state that they may be activated only at certain times with respect to combat just as they apply to spells that state that they may be cast only at certain times with respect to combat.
>
> 506.6d Some spells state that they may be cast “only before (or after) [a particular point in the combat phase],” but don’t meet the additional criteria described in rule 506.6c. If a turn has multiple combat phases, such spells may be cast that turn only before (or after) the stated point of the first combat phase.
>
> 506.6c Some spells state that they may be cast only “during combat” or “during a certain player’s combat phase” in addition to the criteria described in rule 506.6. If a turn has multiple combat phases, such spells may be cast at an appropriate time during any of them.

Comment: Ah, that's it! Also just a note that 506.6g makes 506.6d apply to activating abilities as well as casting spells.

Comment: @Samthere Thank you. I was writing too fast. I added 506.6g to the answer now.